# Prevent celery task from starting until a different task with similar arguments is done

Tags: python, concurrency, celery, distributed-computing, celery-task

Let's say I have a celery task which takes two arguments: `X(a,b)`

I need to implement custom concurrency logic with the following two rules:

1. Instances of `X` can run concurrently if they have different values for `a`. That is, if `X(a=1,b=10)` is running when `X(a=2,b=20)` is added to the queue, then the latter is pulled from the queue and executed immediately.
2. Instances of `X` can NOT run concurrently if they have the same values for `a`. That is, if `X(a=1,b=10)` is running when `X(a=1,b=20)` is added to the queue, then the latter must wait on the queue until the former is done.

Rule #1 comes out of the box with celery by setting `worker_concurrency>1` ([docs](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html#worker-concurrency)). Rule #2 is the tricky one.

Distributed task locking, as described in the [docs](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/tutorials/task-cookbook.html) and in [this blog](http://loose-bits.com/2010/10/distributed-task-locking-in-celery.html), is an approach which gets me close to what I need. There are even libraries out there that implement it for you ([celery-singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42373282/delay-celery-task-based-on-condition)). However, looking back at Rule #2, this approach appears to prevent the second task from being queued until the first task completes. I need it to be queued, just not executed on a worker until the first task completes.

Is there anyway to implement this? [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42373282/delay-celery-task-based-on-condition) asks a similar question but no answer so far.

Comment: The simplest solution could be if you could make "a" into a Celery queue. If "a" only takes few values then that is perhaps easiest way to accomplish what you need. Of course, you must have only one worker with concurrency set to 1 in each of these queues...

Comment: Do you have the ability to change X?

Comment: @DejanLekic not sure what you mean, "a" is an argument for the task function `X`

Comment: @Taterhead not sure what you mean, `X` is a task function which will have code modifications at any point (based on changing business requirements), so the answer is yes

Comment: Allowing our answers to modify X and perhaps push down the tasking to a lower level might yield more elegant solutions.  However, If it from a third party library that is off limits to change, then we think about another approach.

Comment: What i mean is this - if "a" takes few values only, say "foo", "bar", "baz", then instead of argument you can send X() tasks to the appropriate queue...

Comment: @Taterhead `X` is a function in my codebase so, yes, we have the ability to change it

Comment: @DejanLekic "a" can take any value (based on user input). Perhaps I can dynamically spin up a new worker with concurrency=1 for every new value of "a"? Or is that not possible / bad practice?

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be a good case for using [redis](https://redis.io) and bound celery tasks. You can also use redis as your celery broker, if you don't already do that, and as a caching layer if you need that. It's really a swiss army knife. [Deploying redis](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorial_collections/how-to-install-and-secure-redis) is also quite straightforward. I highly encourage anyone to get more familiar with it. It is a great tool to have in one's toolbox.

I will change the example a bit, because I am always confused by single-character functions and variables.

```py
# Think of this as X(a,b) from the question
@task
def add(num1, num2):
    return num1 + num2
```

Then we can upgrade `add` to look more like this:

```py
# "bind" the task so we have access to all the Task base class functionality
# via "self".
# https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.app.task.html#celery.app.task.Task.retry
@task(bind=True)
def add(self, num1, num2):
    if does_running_task_exist_with(num1):
        # requeue. Please visit the docs for "retry" mentioned above.
        # There are also max_retries and some other nice things.
        # Try again in 10s
        self.retry(countdown=10)
        return
    return num1 + num2
```

Our `does_running_task_exist_with` helper function would then use a redis Set. Like all Set implementations, they guarantee uniqueness and checking for existence of a member is fast.

```py
# Using https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py
import redis

def does_running_task_exist_with(some_number):
    # Connect to redis.
    # Using database number 2. You might be using db 0 for celery brokerage,
    # and db 1 for celery result storage. Using a separate DB is just nice
    # for isolation. Redis has up to 16.
    # Connects to localhost by default.
    redis_conn = redis.StrictRedis(db=2)
    # we try adding this number to the Set of currently processing numbers
    # https://redis.io/commands/sadd
    # Return value: the number of elements that were added to the set, 
    # not including all the elements already present into the set.
    members_added = redis_conn.sadd("manager_task_args", str(some_number))
    # Or shortcut it as "return members_added == 0". This here is 
    # more expressive though
    if members_added == 0:
        return True
    return False
```

Alright. Now the tracking and decision making is in place. One important thing missing is: once an `add` task is done, we need to remove the `num1` from the redis set. Let's adjust the function a bit.

```py
import redis

@task(bind=True)
def add(self, num1, num2):
    if does_running_task_exist_with(num1):
        self.retry(countdown=10)
        return
    # Do actual work…
    result = num1 + num2
    # Cleanup
    redis_conn = redis.StrictRedis(db=2)
    redis_conn.srem("manager_task_args", str(num1))
    return result
```

But what if things go wrong? What if the addition fails? Then our `num1` would never be removed from the Set and our queue just starts getting longer and longer. We don't want that. You can do two things here: either create [a class-based task with an `on_failure` method](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#task-inheritance), or wrap it in a try-except-finally. We will go the try-finally route, because it is easier to follow in this case:

```py
import redis

@task(bind=True)
def add(self, num1, num2):
    if does_running_task_exist_with(num1):
        self.retry(countdown=10)
        return
    try:
        result = num1 + num2
    finally:
        redis_conn = redis.StrictRedis(db=2)
        redis_conn.srem("manager_task_args", str(num1))
    return result
```

That should do it. Note that you might also want to look into [redis connection pooling](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py#connection-pools) if you will have tons of tasks.

Comment: Tried this out but this isn't an acceptable solution because (1) Queue order isn't enforced, e.g. queueing task1 before task2 should mean task1 always runs before task2 (2) Compute time and money is wasted running all of these retries (3) Wide range of task execution times leads to MaxRetriesExceededError (I could increase max retries or the countdown argument but that just wastes more compute or increases dead time in between task runs, respectively).

Comment: Totally understandable. Did not realise Queue order is important. The retry approach is definitely a tradeoff on compute time. With all that in mind, I am not entirely sure your needs can be fulfilled with celery.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with you and solved it very simply by using [CeleryOnce](https://github.com/cameronmaske/celery-once)
Simply this library provides you a base class for celery tasks and uses a locking mechanism Redis or file backed. You can even write your own [Celery Task class](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/tasks.html#custom-task-classes) and inherit it from QueueOnce class of this library.

Comment: CeleryOnce is a good idea, but it doesn't meet the requirement #2. Because it raises an error, and has not just blocking the task from being get from the queue. According to TS needs, tasks should stay in the queue until the current job is done. After that, the next task from the queue should been executed. With CeleryOnce it probably can be acheived with retries, like discussed in Luis Nell's answer, but that doesn't solve the resources wasting problem.